# How to install old packages on a server?

Tags: installation, yum, packages

I have been given a task to install PHP 5.3.29 a MySQL 5.5, but both of them are old - are there some repos with old packages? Or how do I get them? I have to install it with yum.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Installing old packages generally is a very bad idea***, especially considering that newer version often are 100% compatible with older one.

That said, each distribution has its own method to revert to a previous package and/or to install a specific software version. For example, with RHEL/Centos/Fedora you can use `yum downgrade <package>` to downgrade an installed package, or `yum install <very_specific_package_version>` to install a specific version.

Comment: Thanks - it will not be installed on a production machine, it is only a step in "test". Thank you